# Code 39 Barcode "1" has a hard time being read by scanners

Tags: barcode

Attached is the image for "1" as a barcode. Some scanners seem to have a hard time reading this. Mine does not. What do you recommend to do in order to fix this?

Items in my database are 1,2,3,4...etc auto increment.

[image: Barcode For "1"]

Comment: have you tried zero padding it? e.g. 000001?

Comment: I don't think this is a SW problem.  Either your scanners aren't good, or how you're printing the barcodes isn't good or clear enough.  Or, you might try a different type of barcode.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for barcode libraries or types of barcodes?

Comment: The ZXing library reads this just fine. Upload it to http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your intercharacter spacing is two white spaces wide.  Have you tried tightening it up a little?  Some scanners are picky about it even though it isn't officially equal to 1 narrow white bar.

Comment: I am using: http://www.sid6581.net/cs/php-scripts/barcode/barcode.phps is there a mistake in the code?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to hardcoded factors affecting bar spacing.  I recommend making the $QuietRatio and the constant in the $QuietBar assignment = $NarrowRatio (i.e. 20) first.

In order to save horizontal real estate most barcode output software generates the intercharacter spacing as identical in width to the narrow bar of the code 3 of 9.  Most documentation misrepresents the intercharacter gap as being defined at exactly one narrow bar in width.  That is likely why some scanners have trouble with a gap of larger width.

Comment: I will try this, but I don't have a barcode scanner to test this with that is broken (I am just going on user reports). Do you have of a non Pear, Non-Zend free barcode generator for php?

Comment: I do not have a scanner, and am not familiar with the latest web-based technologies.  If you use the zoom feature of your browser, you can tell the spaces between the start and stop chars are larger than the smallest spaces within those characters.  It becomes obvious with zoom.  I don't think there is anything else wrong with the software you are using.  You might also try using PNG instead of JPG.  If your users are using something with a small screen, resolution is going to be a big factor.  JPEG is a "lossy" format, PNG is not.  Do you have a model name for the scanners that can't read it?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is what you are seeing, but some scanners are configured by default to only read Code 39 barcodes that are a minimum of two characters long.  Don't ask me why, I don't know.  In any case, you should be able to find a configuration setting for the scanner to tell it to read any length barcode.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will let users know that information.

Comment: In my case this was the issue - the datalogic scanner (TD1100) has as default configuration a minimum character lenght of 2 for code39. i changed the configuration with the aladdin software

Answer (score 1):

I tagged a "0" in front of any numbers less than 10. This seemed to solve the issue without customer's having to tweak their scanners.